# gnu less -N starting with a different line?

Tags: bash, gnu, gnu-coreutils

I would like to use gnu less -N to show line numbers on a text file, but I would like the starting number to be one different than the first line. Is it possible to change the starting line with which gnu less counts the lines yest still show the full file?

For examples:

```
less myfile.txt
_ asfasdfsa
_ asdfadsf
1 asdfsadfasd
2 asdfasdfsadfsad
3 adfasdfsaf
4 asdfasfdsa
5 adfadsfa

wc -l myfile.txt
7
```

Comment: You can't do it using `less`, but should be doable with `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be a trivial task for awk.

```
awk '{s=NR<3?"-":++i;print s,$0}' file
```

in the above example, the line number was added from the 3rd line (the 3 in awk code)

e.g.

```
kent$  seq 7|awk '{s=NR<3?"-":++i;print s,$0}'
- 1
- 2
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 6
5 7
```

you can of course pipe the output to `less` to gain less features. it looks like:

```
awk '{s=NR<3?"-":++i;print s,$0}' file|less
```